# Error this API project is not authorized to use this API. Please Ensure this API is activated in the Console

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, android-maps

I have created an android project that make use of Google Places API. Once I send request for the nearest places am getting this error:

> Error This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please Ensure this API is activated in the Console

I have already enabled Google Places api for Android and am using browser API key. My question is How do I activate my API? Or is it supposed to be purchased?

Comment: browser key? why not android key?

Comment: I read here http://karnshah8890.blogspot.co.ke/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html but still not helping. I had also used android key which did not work

Comment: How do you activate api key please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got solution. I wanted to display nearest places around my location in my android application. I went and created browser api key using my gmail account in google api console. I was doing mistake to enable android google places api. Please don't enable it instead enabled **Google Places API Web Service**. That's how I solved my problem. Any Q am ready to answer

Comment: Perfect solution, Thanks

Comment: I can't explain how many times I created & recreated those STUPID API keys with no success only to switch to your suggestion and see an immediate difference!