# Android | Places API - This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to practice using the places API but I keep getting errors when trying to use the API key. The app is trying to perform a simple nearbysearch but I keep getting the same error message.

I followed the android tutorials to generate a key. Set application restrictions to Android and used the following command to generate the SHA1 keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore.

In the API restrictions tabs I selected Google Places API.

Is there something I'm missing here because I seemed of followed the tutorials step by step, but just can't get it to work.

This question has been asked a number of times before, with many suggesting to select web servers for restrictions, but this fails to work for me.

Comment: Don't use API restrictions tab, it doesn't work and is buggy. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342684/google-maps-api-request-denied-when-using-api-restrictions-key/47468760#47468760. I believe Google already reverted this change, but you have to generate new API key.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll have a look into this after!

Comment: Thanks again for notifying about this. After changing the restriction I started getting a new error, "This API project is not authorized to use this API", which lead me to a post where it was advised to use Place for Web Servers, rather than Places for Android. This fixed the problem I was having and can now make queries with the API. This should really be in the documentation as that pointed me in the wrong direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729568/error-this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-this-api